Nonstandard type script's address
I have nonstandard tx output. txid is 03acfae47d1e0b7674f1193237099d1553d3d8a93ecc85c18c4bec37544fe386.
And I want to express the tx output with specific unique address. Blockchain explorers all seem to use the same convention for representing scriptpubkey.
ex)
https://blockchair.com/ko/bitcoin/transaction/03acfae47d1e0b7674f1193237099d1553d3d8a93ecc85c18c4bec37544fe386
https://3xpl.com/bitcoin/transaction/03acfae47d1e0b7674f1193237099d1553d3d8a93ecc85c18c4bec37544fe386
https://oraclus.com/transaction/bitcoin/03acfae47d1e0b7674f1193237099d1553d3d8a93ecc85c18c4bec37544fe386
How can I derive the address like them?
I tried sha256, sha256+ripemd160, md5 etc.

no :(
I want to know how to derive that address 272edf45031dd498e7b3ae89e11ff21b string.
Blockchair and other places use the same encoding.

Blockchair and 3xpl are projects by the same people. I have never heard of oraclus, and I don’t think this representation of non-standard outputs is used broadly.

Some other blockchain explorers show the address as NULL or UNKNOWN. Someone raised a support request at Blockchair for this. See https://github.com/Blockchair/Blockchair.Support/issues/1487

s-272edf45031dd498e7b3ae89e11ff21b is a special address in Bitcoin history: it's an error made by MtGox in 2011. It's not a valid address, it was named like that for unknown reasons.
You can find more about it here:
https://news.bitcoin.com/bitcoin-history-part-17-that-time-mt-gox-destroyed-2609-btc/

This doesn't answer the question. It might very well not be answerable unless Blockchair shares how their internal format works, or someone reverse-engineers it.
